# Synchronization of ICollection

Tags: c#, collections

When observe the definition of

*`ICollection extends IEnumerable. It provides size and synchronization members in addition to enumeration.`*

Does synchronization here represent the synchronization of collection ,when it is shared 
by multiple threads?.Kindly explain me with simple example how can i practically use  "`ICollection.IsSynchronized Property`".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`IsSynchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.issynchronized.aspx) is true, the collection should be thread-safe. However, you still may have to use a lock around multiple list operations (such as finding and index before inserting or whatever) and in this case you can use the [`SyncRoot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot.aspx) property.

Note, however, that both members are only present in the non-generic [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1ht6113(default).aspx) interface. The newer (.NET 2) [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) interface doesn't offer them, and frankly, usually you're going to lock yourself instead of using a synchronized list.